# How to make a template field(textbox) as a part of the datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable, templatefield

I have a GridView .

its data source is a `data table` i create it pro-grammatically in `.cs` to suit what i wanna to show. Now i wanna more column in this gridview as a **template field containing a text box**.(as a part of my data table). How to do this .Please if there is a sample or example this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following tutorial will help you. This is on ASP.net 2.0 but there will not be a much different on latest versions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx

Added Few other resources based on new comment

1. http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/29_Creating_Datagrid_columns_programmatically.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/create_template_columns.aspx?df=100&forumid=281019&exp=0&select=1726624

Answer (score 1):

TemplateField bfield = new TemplateField();

bfield.HeaderTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Header, col.ColumnName);

bfield.ItemTemplate = new GridViewTemplate(ListItemType.Item, col.ColumnName);

GrdView1.Columns.Add(bfield);

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MyTextField">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtField">
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

More details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx

However, I think you're looking to do more than just this - but I can't be certain....

Comment: hmmm thanks but,I know how to do this.this isn't what i ask about. my data source is a data table created programatically.